# How to connect to external program

Tags: java, ipc, credentials

I would like to connect to external program using my 'mini' project, and because i'm new in Java i want to ask you what is the best way to do that.
Running my project, user see window where have to insert login and password - here i would like to use the same login and password as in external program which is running from .exe file:

[image]

The purpose of my program is to send emails with different content / information / data. So far I have created an interface, which can, for example, generate an email with the relevant information in Outlook. But in addition, I would like to add (for example in attachment) in this email information from this external program - let say some kind of instruction assigned to the problem (example). I would like to make something like that to avoid having to run two or even three separate programs.

Comment: Which external program is that? You may need to refer the API of the program/executable to fetch the credentials!

Comment: It's some kind of program using in my work... Ok, so how can this be done?

Comment: How can this be done? That's very hard to say at this moment. Could you provide more details on just what you're trying to do, more about the program you appear to be trying to drive, more about what you are trying to get your own code to do. Details matter.

Comment: So purpose of my program is to send emails with different content / information / data. So far I have created an interface, which can, for example, generate an email with the relevant information in Outlook. But in addition, I would like to add (for example in attachment) in this email information from this external program - let say some kind of instruction assigned to the problem (example). I would like to make something like that to avoid having to run two or even three separate programs.

Comment: As far as I understood, you are trying to catch saved credentials from an external program. So that you do not need to re-enter it again in your helper-program. Well, first thing, do you have access to the source code of the external program and are able to change it? I assume no, then it heavily depends on what the external program is, how it saves the data (for example in a configuration file on your drive), how it communicates, etc. Trying to grab arbitrary data is definitely nothing for a beginner, here we are in the field of reverse-engineering, memory manipulation, injection, ...

Comment: Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 0):

For your mailing need, if it's for single mail sending and you want an easy and fast solution, you could try to use a java robot which opens your outlook and which fill data. If you have good shortcuts in outlook, it's simple to do. 
Nevertheless this solution is not solid because of potential interactions with other windows event during robot processing. So, you should check that the mail was correctly filled.
If you want a more reliable solution but more hard to implement,  or you want to do multiple mail sending, you could use JavaMail api to send mail(s).

In general, in Java you have multiple ways to communicate data with external programs according your external program possibilities:

- program parameters when launching
- program api (java or not)
- robot api java